# How to extract first string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I have a regex question.

I have a list of files below.

```
df <- c("Alilis CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx" , "Ana T. CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx" , "Ana V. CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx","Anita CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx")

[1] "Alilis CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx" "Ana T. CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx" "Ana V. CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx" "Anita CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx"
```

I need to extract the name at the beginning of the string but there are a short letter with dot (`e.g. Ana V.`) I was not able to extract the letters.

With the code below,

```
unique(word(df, 1))
[1] "Alilis" "Ana"    "Anita"
```

How can I get ?

```
[1] "Alilis" "Ana T."  "Ana V."  "Anita"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
gsub("^((\\S+)|^(\\w+ [A-Z]\\.))\\s+.*", "\\1", df)
[1] "Alilis" "Ana T." "Ana V." "Anita"
```

Should also work if there are multiple spaces

```
> gsub("^((\\S+)|^(\\w+ [A-Z]\\.))\\s+.*", "\\1", c(df, "Allis hello CELF-4_Data_Entry.xlsx"))
[1] "Alilis" "Ana T." "Ana V." "Anita"  "Allis"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
sub("\\s+\\S+$", "", df)

[1] "Alilis" "Ana T." "Ana V." "Anita"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option assuming you want everything before ' CELF' like this:

```r
df <- c("Alilis CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx" , "Ana T. CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx" , "Ana V. CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx","Anita CELF-4_CF_Data_Entry.xlsx")

library(stringr)
word(df,1,sep = "\\ CELF")
#> [1] "Alilis" "Ana T." "Ana V." "Anita"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `extract` and positive lokahead:

```
library(tidyr)
data.frame(df) %>%
  extract(df,
          into = "Name",
          regex = "(.*?)\\sCELF")
    Name
1 Alilis
2 Ana T.
3 Ana V.
4  Anita
```

The `regex`part captures anything that is **before** ...

- `\\s`: one whitespace character followed by ...
- `CELF`: ... the literal string `CELF`

Answer (score 2):

We can try `sub` with pattern `(\\S+(\\s\\w\\.)?).*`, i.e.,

```
> sub("(\\S+(\\s\\w\\.)?).*", "\\1", df)
[1] "Alilis" "Ana T." "Ana V." "Anita"
```